# What does this BASH shell script excerpt do?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

Can you explain the following code please (assume that HOST contains a string):

```
HOST=${HOST//$'\n'/}
```

If the above line was declared inside a function, would the variable "HOST" be available to other functions in the same script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to *Substring Replacement* subchapter from the [ABS guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

```
HOST=${HOST//$'\n'/}
```

removes *all* occurrences of the newline character `$'\n'` in the `HOST` variable.

> If the above line was declared inside a function, would the variable
>   `HOST` be available to other functions in the same script?

Yes, assuming `HOST` wasn't declared using bash [`local`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html) keyword.

Comment: Thank you, that has been very helpful, I will read the rest of the manual you linked. The second question was to clarify what I thought I already knew, but for some reason this variable is empty when used in another function.

Comment: @ViniH: if both functions are called within the same process (you assume no parent to child or child to parent communication), then I see no reason for such misbehavior. If only the `HOST` variable contains nothing but newline symbols, once these are removed in one function, the other one could indeed see the variable as empty.

Comment: Thank you, on further investigation it is spawning child threads.

Comment: The ABS is, in general, not the best guide. The Bash reference manual and the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are better.

Comment: @ViniH: you should export your variable to make it visible in a child process.